# MS Graph API: Fetch channel messages

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft.Graph.Beta version="0.7.0-preview" to fetch channel list and then to fetch messages from those channels. 
I have an app registered in the azure portal.

I am able to fetch the channel list from the MsTeams but the API to fetch messages is throwing error which has just "Code: UnknownError
Inner error".

Code:

```
var messages = graphClient.Teams[groupId].Channels[channelId].Messages.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Error:

> ```
>      at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
> ```
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__35.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__31`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Graph.ChannelMessagesCollectionRequest.d__4.MoveNext()

Comment: Please take a look at [Get Channel Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0) using Graph API.Let us know if you face any issue with it.

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT for the reply. I was actually following the same Graph API. The error message seems to be very generic so difficult to know the cause.
I was guessing if this could be related to permission issue but I have already granted Application permission Group.Read.All and Group.ReadWrite.All. I was wondering why we would required Group.ReadWrite.All since that API just fetches messages. 
In the Notes section of that API documentation, it mentioned that API is protected and must submit request to MS. I have not yet submitted this request. Do I need this?

Comment: Please go ahead raise the request.

Comment: Yeah. Once we get this request granted from MS, it worked. Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT